# How to send simple email using Python

Tags: python, linux, email, smtp

Before you mark this as a duplicate; I've read the other threads as well. I'm trying to send an email as simple as using the mail() function in php. I simply tried [the example from the official python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html). But when I try to connect with the localhost on my linux machine I get:

```
>>> import smtplib
>>> smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 251, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 311, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 286, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
    raise err
error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

I thought this example didn't need an email server to run (just like the php mail() function doesn't need an email-server to run).

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong or how I can get this to send an email? All tips are welcome!

Comment: Do you have `mail server` on your localhost ? If not then you can't connect to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The php `mail()` function *does* need a relay to send messages. It [defaults to `sendmail`](http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.sendmail-path) on Linux machines.

On Windows you have to [give it the address of a SMTP server](http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.smtp).

In order for any program to send email, you need to connect to a SMTP server. There is no running around that.

Comment: Ah! I never knew the php mail() function actually needed an external program (because it always "just worked"). But I just `sudo apt-get install`ed sendmail, and now it works like a charm! Thanks for enlightening me!